# FFMPEG not moving text

Tags: image, go, video, ffmpeg

So I'm trying to add scrolling text to a video using ffmpeg (using Golang to execute a ffmpeg command)

I am using this command to test how text moves:

```
"ffmpeg -y -i %s -filter_complex \"[0]split[txt][orig];[txt]drawtext=fontfile=font/Amejo.ttf:fontsize=20:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2+20:y=t:text='" + strings.Join(strings.Split(verse.Translation, " "), "\n") + "':bordercolor=black:line_spacing=20:borderw=3[txt];[orig]crop=iw:50:0:0[orig];[txt][orig]overlay\" -c:v libx264 -y -preset ultrafast %s"
```

I have set the y = t, expecting it to move the text. However my text just stays stationary, I have no idea why.

This is an example output (Its a video but this is all it shows the entire video):
[image: Screenshot of the video, the video is stationary, no text moves]

Thanks